# phpmyadmin multiple values in one column

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, xampp

I would like to ask you, does it possible to create a column in phpmyadmin where I could insert (import) more than one value in one column. As example I create a table with name mytable then added column1 (with value 1) and now i would like to add column2(with values 3 5 8).

When I try to do that it only show column2 with value 3 in it... It ignores 5 and 8.

Comment: Forget about more values in one column. It's a bad practice

Comment: "When I try to do that"  try to do that _how_? You haven't shown us what you're trying.  As already indicated though, unless you can give really good justification for it, this is probably a bad idea.

Comment: @panther could you please explain me why ? I'm new at this. Also I really need to have those values in one column. I have 20k records and in that column it might be 1 value or 5 values like 1 2 3 4 5

Comment: @nerukazz: impossible flitering, ordering and other problems. Right solution is to create second table where will be 1 to 5 rows for each from 20k records.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## You can, but don't

Technically a single database field can store multiple values by storing them in a comma-separated string, or a JSON-encoded string. Many newer versions of MySql also support storing complex objects in a [Json Datatype](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html), which can hold just about anything. However, it is usually a bad idea to do this, and goes against the intent of a relational database.

#### Instead consider creating a separate column for each value.

## Better, store optional values in another table.

Rather than attempting to define a single column to store varying data, create a new table, which references the rows on the first table. Below is an example of a [Many-to-One](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-to-many_(data_model)) data relationship which would solve your problem.

```
table a
-------
id, name, column1
1,  'A',  1
2,  'B',  5

table b
------- 
id, a_id, column2
81, 1,    3
82, 1,    5
83, 1,    8
94, 2,    1
95, 2,    2
96, 2,    3
97, 2,    4
98, 2,    5
```

By joining these two table, you have a similar result set which is both much more flexible, and sortable/searchable/filterable.

```
SELECT a.id, a.name, a.column1, b.column2
FROM a
LEFT JOIN b ON a.id = b.a_id
```

Comment: **A note about _why_ it's bad to put multiple values in one-column:** doing anything with those values means you have to decode them to work with them, and encode them again to save them. This would virtually guarantee that your code would be more complex, perform worse, and be much more difficult to maintain. Additionally, any sql queries trying to lookup values in that composite column within a WHERE clause, would run extremely slowly compared to most other data-structures.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to "*can I do it*" is **"yes"**. However, the answer to "*should I do it*" is **"*try to find another way*"**. For example if I have a string like:

```
$mystring = "1 2 3 4 5";
```

If I execute a query to insert this into a table column field it will insert it. If this is the only way you can tackle your algorithm then I suggest you insert data values split with `/` or `-` so when you retrieve you can `explode` them and get their values, but I do not suggest doing it this way. Instead, I suggest you to try and find another solution to your problem before you go for this one.